# How to get immediate parent Id of the child id in array of nested json Object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, recursion, nested

I need to get the parent id of the specific child.

Here is my sample JSON, If I give entity id 32 it should return 6 as parent Id and if I give 30 it should return 5 as parent id.

```js
const arr =  [{
    "id": 0,
    "name": "My Entity",
    "children": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "MARKET",
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "Sales",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "id": 3,
                            "name": "District 1",
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "id": 5,
                                    "name": "Area 1",
                                    "children": [
                                        {
                                            "entityId": 30,
                                            "id": 26,
                                            "name": "Mumbai"
                                        },
                                        {

                                            "entityId": 31,
                                            "id": 26,
                                            "name": "Hyderabad"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "num": 0,
                                },
                                {
                                    "id": 6,
                                    "name": "Area 2",
                                    "children": [
                                        {
                                            "entityId": 32,
                                            "id": 32,
                                            "name": "Karnataka"
                                        },
                                        {

                                            "entityId": 33,
                                            "id": 33,
                                            "name": "Andhra Pradesh"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "num": 0,
                                },
                            ]
                        },
                    ]
                },
            ]
        },
    ]
}]
```

Here is the code I have tried

```js
const findParent = (arr, entityId) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i].entityId === entityId) {
            return [];
        } else if (arr[i].children && arr[i].children.length) {
            const t = findParents(arr[i].children, entityId);

            if (t !== false) {
                t.push(arr[i].id);

                return t;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
};

findParents(arr, 30);
```

But it is returning like below

```
[
    5,
    3,
    2,
    1,
    0
]
```

But I want the output to be

```
[
  5
]
```

Kindly help me on this, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace this:

```
t.push(arr[i].id);
```

with:

```
if (t.length == 0) t.push(arr[i].id);
```

Comment: wow!! It's working as expected, Thank you Mr.trincot . could u please tell how it works if possible.

Comment: This extra condition makes the `push` to execute only once. The next time it encounters this `if`, the array already has an element, and so the condition is no longer true. So all other values you would have appended to the array in the original code, are no longer appended to it now.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest easier solution

```
const findParent = (arr, entityId) => {
  const children = arr.flatMap(parent => 
    (item.children || []).map(child => ({ parent, child, entityId: child.entityId }))
  )

  const res = children.find(item => item.entityId === entityId)
  return res.entityId || findChildren(res.map(v => v.child), entityId)
}
```