# Get values from immediate parent for any given child in array of nested JSON objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Here is a sample of my JSON.

```
const data = [{
   "employees": [ 
      {         
         "employee": [
            {
               "name": "Jon",
               "surname": "Smith",
               "leaveRequest": [
                  {
                     "id": "3000",
                     "approver": "Terry"
                  }
               ]
            }],
      },
      {
         "employee": [
            {
               "name": "Mike",
               "surname": "Jones",
               "leaveRequest": [
                  {
                     "id": "1700",
                     "approver": "Mary"
                  }
               ]
            },
         ]
      }
   ]
}];
```

I want to be able to search by id across all leaveRequests and get the employee's name and surname.

If I pass id "3000" I would like to be able to get an object ["name": "Jon", "surname": "Smith"]

I've tried implementing the solution from: [How to get immediate parent Id of the child id in array of nested json Object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62426283/how-to-get-immediate-parent-id-of-the-child-id-in-array-of-nested-json-object)

This is what I've tried:

```
const findEmployee = (arr, id) => {
   for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if (arr[i].id === id) {
         return [];
      } 
      else if (arr[i].employee && arr[i].employee.length) {
         const t = findEmployee(arr[i].employee, id);

         if (t !== false) {
         if (t.length == 0) 
            t.push({"name": arr[i].name, "surname": arr[i].surname});
            return t;
         }
      }
   }
   return false;
};

console.log(findEmployee(data, "3000"))
```

But the solution in that thread relies on each child node having the same key 'children' which wouldn't work in my scenario. I'd have to restructure my JSON structure to be:

```
employee
    employee
       employee
          id
```

And this doesn't make sense in my scenario. How can I search by id across all leaveRequests and get the employee's name and surname from the immediate parent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest walking through the object recursively, and returning if we find an object with a `leaveRequest` property.

Once we find this we'll strip off the leaveRequest and return the rest of the object.

Edit: This will now work with multiple leave requests per employee.

```js
const data = [{ "employees": [ { "employee": [ { "name": "Jon", "surname": "Smith", "leaveRequest": [ { "id": "2990", "approver": "Kim" } , { "id": "3000", "approver": "Terry" } ] }], }, { "employee": [ { "name": "Mike", "surname": "Jones", "leaveRequest": [  { "id": "1200", "approver": "Jane" }, { "id": "1700", "approver": "Mary" } ] }, ] } ] }]; 

function findRequest(input, id) {
    if (input.leaveRequest && input.leaveRequest.find(lr => lr.id == id)) {
        // Return everything bar the leave request...
        return (({ leaveRequest, ...obj}) => obj)(input);
    }
    for(let k in input) {
        if (input[k] && typeof(input[k]) === 'object') {
            let leaveRequest = findRequest(input[k], id);
            if (leaveRequest) return leaveRequest;
        }
    }
}

let ids = [1700, 3000];
ids.forEach(id => console.log('id: ', id, '\nrequest:', findRequest(data, id)));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: thanks for this. I simplified my data for the sake of the question but I actually have multiple items inside the leave request node. If I search for the first id in there it works as expected (I guess that's that leaveRequest[0] is doing), but not if I try searching for a id that isn't the top one. Can you tell me how I could update the function to search all of the ids? Apologies again for not stating this in the original question.

Comment: I've updated to handle the case where each employee has multiple leave requests. I've updated the example data too. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much - that's perfect, been trying to work this out for days!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer using [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan):

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script type="module">
import objectScan from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/object-scan@18.3.0/lib/index.min.js';

const data = [{ employees: [{ employee: [{ name: 'Jon', surname: 'Smith', leaveRequest: [{ id: '3000', approver: 'Terry' }] }] }, { employee: [{ name: 'Mike', surname: 'Jones', leaveRequest: [{ id: '1700', approver: 'Mary' }] }] }] }];

const find = objectScan(['[*].employees[*].employee[*].leaveRequest[*].id'], {
  abort: true, // abort after first result
  filterFn: ({ value, context }) => value === context, // find the correct id
  rtn: ({ parents }) => parents[2] // return the correct node
});

console.log(find(data, '3000'));
// => { name: 'Jon', surname: 'Smith', leaveRequest: [ { id: '3000', approver: 'Terry' } ] }
</script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)

Comment: thanks, that looks like a really useful script. I didn't mention in the original question but I'm using this within an Expo app on React Native so when I tried to add your package and compile the app I ran into some errors. Do you have any plans to make this compatible with React Native/Expo? If not I'm sure I'll be using it on other projects that aren't react based

Comment: @sains23 What error were you getting? This should work in react.

Answer (score 1):

Part of the challenge is the data is oddly shaped, with objects containing single-element arrays and arrays containing single-keyed objects. I'd start by reshaping the data to something more rational (using an assumption that the data isn't recursive -- employees don't contain other employees).

```
// create a flat array of employees [ employeeA, employeeB, ...
const employees = data[0].employees.map(object => object.employee[0]);
```

With that, the way to go from a `leaveRequest` `id` to the containing employee is to build an index. Here, another assumption is that leaveRequest ids are unique.

```
// create an index { leaveIdX: employeeC, leaveIdY: employeeD, ...
const leaveRequestIndex = employees.reduce((index, employee) => {
  employee.leaveRequest.forEach(request => index[request.id] = employee);
  return index;
}, {});
```

That provides an O(1) lookup from leaveRequest to employee, like this...

```
// given someLeaveRequestId, get the containingEmployee
const containingEmployee = leaveRequestIndex[someLeaveRequestId];
```

Testing on the OP data...

```js
// create a flat array of employees [ { employee }, { employee }, ...
const employees = data()[0].employees.map(object => object.employee[0]);

// create an index { leaveId: { employee }, leaveId: { employee }, ...
const leaveRequestIndex = employees.reduce((index, employee) => {
  employee.leaveRequest.forEach(request => index[request.id] = employee);
  return index;
}, {});

// test it: which employee has leave request 3001?
const employee = leaveRequestIndex[3001];
const { name, surname } = employee;
console.log(name, surname);


function data() {
  return [{
   "employees": [ 
      {         
         "employee": [
            {
               "name": "Jon",
               "surname": "Smith",
               "leaveRequest": [
                  {
                     "id": "3000",
                     "approver": "Terry"
                  },
                  {
                     "id": "3001",
                     "approver": "Larry"
                  }
               ]
            }],
      },
      {
         "employee": [
            {
               "name": "Mike",
               "surname": "Jones",
               "leaveRequest": [
                  {
                     "id": "1700",
                     "approver": "Mary"
                  }
               ]
            },
         ]
      }
   ]
}];
}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. I'll take a look. Out of interest how would you suggest organising the data to be better shaped in the first place other than `employees > employee > leaveRequest > individual requests` ? Genuinely open to suggestions as we're still quite early in the development...

Comment: @sains23, I suggest a shape for the data in this answer: a simple array of objects where each represents an employee.  I suggest flattening the structure given in the OP, even if employees contain other employees.